# Solving the roots of Redlich Kwong Equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Good evening everyone.

After studying some equations of state, I've read about the mathematical steps formulated to model some. In the particular case of Van der Waals, where
$$P=\frac{RT}{v-b}-\frac{a}{v^2}$$

For those not familiar with this expression, this equation describes general characteristics of a real gas, P standing for pressure, R for the universal gas constant, T for temperature, v for molar volume (Yep, I know the little line is missing, sorry!), and a and b are characteristic constants for the gas .

There are some special values for Temperature, Pressure and Molar volume. Finding them, apparently, helps me in my quest for a and b. I am told the following steps to do so in VdW equation:

1) Derive the function twice.

2) Solve RT for each derivative and make them equal to zero.Make an equation of of the derivative and the second derivative, then solve for v

3) Plug the value of V in the first derivative, and solve for T, now called critical temperature. [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuzQk.png)

4) Plug the values of V and T in the original function, thus obtaining the critical pressure. [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7ii6.png)

5) Solve "a" for critical T and critical P, then making the equation and obtaining "b"[5]

6) Plug "b" in critical T, now obtaining "a"[6]

Now, back to my problem, I'm looking for "a" and "b" again, but now in the Redlich Kwong equation:
$$P=\frac{RT}{v-b}-\frac{a}{\sqrt(T)*(v^2+vb)}$$
I've already derived the function twice and solved for RT:
$$P'=\frac{-RT}{(v-b)^2}+\frac{a(2v+b)}{\sqrt(T)*((v^2+vb)^-2)}=0$$
$$RT=\frac{a(2v+b)*((v-b)^2}{\sqrt(T)*((v^2+vb)^-2)}$$

$$P''=\frac{2RT}{(v-b)^-3}+\frac{2a}{\sqrt(T)*((v^2+vb)^-2)}-\frac{2a*(2v+b)^2}{\sqrt(T)*((v^2+vb)^-3)}=0$$
$$RT=\frac{a}{\sqrt(T)}*((v-b)^3)*(\frac{(2v+b)^2}{((v^2)+vb)^3}-\frac{1}{(v^2)+vb)^2})$$

After putting the two =0, I've obtained this far:
$$3v+2b=(v-b)*((2v+b)^2)((v^2)+vb)$$

As it isn't as simple as in the VdW case, I certainly don't know where to go now in order to obtain a value of v based on b. I would be so grateful if someone checked this, thank you!

Comment: [5]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PV05c.png [6]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iFGIL.png the pictures for the remaining steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put a second answer to show you how the work can be done in a simpler manner.

Start with the equation of state $$P=\frac{R T}{V-b}-\frac{a}{\sqrt{T}\, V (b+V)}\tag 1$$ and develop it in terms of $V$; this leads to a cubic polynomial in $V$ $$V^3-\frac{R T}{P} V^2+ \left(\frac{a}{P \sqrt{T}}-b^2-\frac{b R T}{P}\right)V-\frac{a b}{P
   \sqrt{T}}=0$$ Now, at the critical point $(T=T_c, P=P_c)$, this must be identical to the development of $$(V-V_c)^3=V^3-3V_c V^2+3V_c^2V-V_c^3$$ Now, by identification $$3V_c=\frac{R T_c}{P_c}\tag 2$$ $$3V_c^2=\frac{a}{P_c \sqrt{T_c}}-b^2-\frac{b R T_c}{P_c}\tag 3$$ $$V_c^3=\frac{a b}{P_c
   \sqrt{T_c}}\tag 4$$ So, we can only use equations $(3)$ and $(4)$ to identify $a$ and $b$.

From $(4)$ we can express $a$ as a function of $b$ and plug it in $(3)$; this gives now a cubic equation in $b$; solve it and go back to the definition we made of $a$ as a function of $b$.

**Edit**

More details. From $(2)$ we have $V_c=\frac{R T_c}{3 P_c}$ this makes the cubic in $b$ to be $$b^3+\frac{b^2 R T_c}{P_c}+\frac{b R^2 T_c^2}{3 P_c^2}-\frac{R^3 T_c^3}{27 P_c^3}=0$$ Define now $b=\frac{B RT_c}{P_c}$; this makes the equation $$27 B^3+27B^2+9B-1=0$$ Using Cardano method, there is only one real root which is $$B=\frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt[3]{2}-1\right)\implies b=\frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt[3]{2}-1\right)\frac{ RT_c}{P_c}$$ Now, $(4)$ becomes $$\Big(\frac{R T_c}{3 P_c}\Big)^3=\frac{a b}{P_c
   \sqrt{T_c}}=\frac{a }{P_c
   \sqrt{T_c}}\frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt[3]{2}-1\right)\frac{ RT_c}{P_c} \implies a=\frac{R^2 T_c^{5/2}}{9 \left(\sqrt[3]{2}-1\right) P_c}$$

Comment: You were absolutely right! There was a way simpler method. And it actually makes a lot of sense, considering how we develop the polynomial in order to make iterations to obtain Vc. I'll do the calculus for the method myself as well to have the experience. I am extremely grateful for your help! I'll make sure to keep up with your posts here, as I'm new to the forum. I hope you have an excellent week.

Comment: And, what if I tell you that there is another simpler method based on the compressibility factor $Z=\frac{PV}{RT}$ ?

Comment: Sounds terrific! Would you please enlighten us? The application of the compressibility factor has always been tricky for me as the relationship between a "real" gas and the ideal model makes no room in my head for the different state equations. I usually stick to diagrams rather than calculus whenever I need it.

Answer (score 1):

Even if there exist much simpler procedures to get the characteristic constants of cubic equations of state, let us do it using almost what you have been suggested.

Using $$P=\frac{R T}{V-b}-\frac{a}{\sqrt{T} V (b+V)}\tag 1$$ $$P'=\frac 1{\sqrt T}\Big(\frac{a (b+2 V)}{V^2 (b+V)^2}-\frac{R T^{3/2}}{(b-V)^2}\Big)\tag2$$ $$P''=\frac 1{\sqrt T}\Big(\frac{a \left(\frac{1}{(b+V)^3}-\frac{1}{V^3}\right)}{b}+\frac{R T^{3/2}}{(V-b)^3}\Big)\tag3$$ SInce, at the critical point, $P'=P''=0$, equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ can rewrite as $$\frac{R T^{3/2}}{(V-b)^2}=\frac{a (b+2 V)}{V^2 (b+V)^2}\tag 4$$ $$\frac{R T^{3/2}}{(V-b)^3}=-\frac{a \left(\frac{1}{(b+V)^3}-\frac{1}{V^3}\right)}{b}\tag 5$$ Now, making the ratio ($(4)$ divided by $(5)$) and simplifying, we then get $$V-b=\frac{V (b+V) (b+2 V)}{b^2+3 b V+3 V^2}\tag 6$$ Cross multiplying and   simplifying, we then get $$-b^3-3 b^2 V-3 b V^2+V^3=0$$ which is an homogeneous polynomial of degree $3$. Setting $V=x b$, we then need to solve $$x^3-3 x^2-3 x-1=0$$ Using Cardano method, the only real solution is given by $$x=1+2^{2/3}+2^{1/3}$$

I am sure that you can continue from here.

Comment: Hello and thank you! It amazes me how close the value of V is to Van der Waals, I thought it would be a completely different value. However,  why is inyour first derivative : $(b-v)^2$ ? isn't it $(v-b)^2$ ? . Also, which other methods fo you know? It would be interesting to know them! Hope you have a nice day

Comment: You would me amazed : I spent more than 50 years with cubic equations of state. May be this http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0378381293851142 could be of interest if you can access it. Otherwise, if you are really interested by a simpler method, let me know. Cheers.

Comment: I definitely am! I'll make sure to give a good eye to your work; This far, equations of state have been absolutely amazing for me. As soon as I manage to get through this one, I'll give it a try. Thanks for everything.

Comment: @Farad. If you are interested by equations of state and want to discuss, it will be a pleasure for me. You can contact me by e-mail (my address is in my profile).